# is there anyway to read device contact list in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to read the phone contact list. I don't want to read sim contacts and synced contacts. I have tried two three days to find out a solution for this.

- I can read sim contacts
- I can read full phone contacts(including phone, google, sim and facebook)

I don't need google or sim or any other contact. I need only phone contacts which I stored in 
my phone contact memory.

Comment: [see this tuts...](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-read-contact-and-display-in.html)

Comment: thankx for the response yaar. But I want phone contact which i saved in my phone memory. i dnt want sim contact

Answer (score 1):

The following code may help you.

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
```

Comment: Thanks Anu .. But my question is different,i am not asking about phone number. I want to read the full contact list stored in device memory. any idea??